# Why is Mockito @Mock creating a non-mock instance?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a handful of very similar projects, all Java, SpringBoot, and Maven.  All of them have one class with the same name, and almost identical contents.  I added an additional method in one of them, the class with the problem I'm going to describe, but I'm pretty sure that detail is a coincidence.

Each project also has a test class corresponding to that very similar class, and the skeleton of that test class is identical in each class.  The test class has an `@InjectMocks` for the class under test (CUT), and two `@Mock` annotations, one of which corresponds to an instance variable of the CUT.

The test class does have a `@Before` method that creates an instance variable used by the tests.

All the variations of the test class have "`@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`".

If I run one of the "good" tests and set a breakpoint on the first line of the @Before method and then look at the "this" variables in the variables pane, I see the types of the two @Mock-ed instance variables end with "$MockitoMock".

If I do the same thing in the "bad" test, the types of the two @Mock-ed variables do NOT end with "`$MockitoMock`".  In fact, these appear to be normal instances of the corresponding classes, not mocked classes.

Even more curious, in the "bad" test, I tried making explicit calls to "`instvar = mock(clazz.class)`" in the `@Before` method, and after I step over those, the type of the instance variable is STILL not a mocked type, HOWEVER, when I click on the instance variable, the toString panel shows "`Mock for ..., hashCode: 1028811481`".  If I "Resume" at this point, I can hit a breakpoint in the allegedly mocked class, with that same instance whose toString value says "`Mock for ...`".

That's the issue in words.  Now I guess I'll show some code.

Here's part of the "bad" test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RestClientTest {
    @InjectMocks
    RestClient restClient;

    @Mock
    RestClientFactory restClientFactory;

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(new HttpHeaders());
        restClientFactory   = mock(RestClientFactory.class);
        restTemplate        = mock(RestTemplate.class);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(restClient, "restClientFactory", restClientFactory);
    }
```

Here's part of the "good" test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RestClientTest {
    @InjectMocks
    RestClient restClient;

    @Mock
    RestClientFactory restClientFactory;

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(new HttpHeaders());
    }
```

I've determined that both "good" and "bad" projects are using version 2.15.0 of mockito-core.

**Update**:

I tried stepping into the "mock" call in the bad test, and set breakpoints there, because it goes here from annotation processing, so I can see the behavior of both the bad and good case.

Here's what I saw in the good case:

[image: first breakpoint of good case]

I stepped over until line 65 and stepped into "createMock()".  That put me in the MockUtil class:

[image: in MockUtil.createMock]

The type of "mockMaker" is "org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker".

I stepped to line 35 and stepped into the "mockMaker.createMock()" method:

[image: In BBMM.createMock()]

Now let's start over and run the "bad" case:

We first hit the initial breakpoint:
[image: first breakpoint in bad case]

And then here:
[image: second breakpoint in bad case]

Now we see that the type of "mockMaker" is DIFFERENT from the good case.  The type is "org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker".

I'm not going to continue to step through this, but this path does produce the "fake mock" with the different toString value.

Now that I think about it, this instance is like a "spy" in that it's managed by Mockito, but all the methods call the original class method by default.  I have no clue why it takes a different path here.

I would hope that this is enough information to give a clue to someone who better understands how this works.

Comment: Not a direct answer (hence comment, but) A mock created through the `@Mock` annotation will _not_ have it's `toString()` overridden with the "mock for Type ..." (I believe it will instead just be the name of the field...  But I could be wrong).

Comment: That's correct, that is consistent with the "good" test. I get the feeling that that "Mock for ... hashcode" is from something else, but I can't imagine what, or how it got there.

Comment: The ones which have that `toString` are the ones you create in the `@Before` method (through the `Mockito.mock` method).

Comment: In the "bad" class, the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` annotations don't seem very relevant, since your `setup` method is immediately overwriting everything Mockito did. The important question is, what is the `mock` method that `setup` is calling? Are you sure that it's Mockito's `mock` method? (I guess what I'm saying is: please post a *minimal*, *complete* "bad" class.)

Comment: Although I did add those lines, my breakpoint is at the top of the setup method, before those lines are executed. Even if they were created by those lines, how could Mockito.mock() be doing that?

Comment: The other thing to note is that I added a no-args constructor to the RestClientFactory class, with a print statement and a breakpoint, and it does NOT hit the breakpoint, so it's not a pure Mockito mock, and it's not an ordinary instance either.

Comment: @ruakh, I didn't notice your comment until after I wrote the last two, but what I said should address that.  I'm inspecting those variables even before it executes those lines.

Comment: And to be clear, when I step over those lines in setup, it produces the same kind of "fake mock" that the annotation processing produced.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr: The only difference between the code you've posted in the "good" class and the code you've posted in the "bad" class is that the "bad" class has those extra lines in its `setup` method. So if you're now saying that those extra lines aren't even relevant, then again: please post a *minimal*, *complete* "bad" class.

Comment: If I knew how to do that, I wouldn't be posting this question. There's effectively no difference between them that I can see.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr: The general way to do it is experimentation. First: is this consistent/reproducible? Next: does it remain consistent/reproducible if you remove field X? How about field Y? How about if you replace field Z with a standard JDK class that doesn't depend on the rest of your project? Once you've removed everything that you can remove while still reproducing the problem, you post the complete set of that "everything".

Comment: I found some clues, I'll update the post with more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The type of "mockMaker" [in the "good" case] is "org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyMockMaker".

> Now [in the "bad" case] we see that the type of "mockMaker" is DIFFERENT from the good case. The type is "org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker".

So, the "good" project is using the default mock-maker, which uses subclassing — see [ByteBuddyMockMaker.java](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/creation/bytebuddy/ByteBuddyMockMaker.java) — while the "bad" project is using a non-default mock-maker that tries to use [Java instrumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) to avoid subclassing: [InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/creation/bytebuddy/InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java). That matches up with the behavior difference that you observed

According to the Javadoc for InlineByteBuddyMockMaker:

> This mock maker **must to be activated explicitly** for supporting mocking final types and methods:
>
> This mock maker can be activated by creating the file `/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` containing the text `mock-maker-inline` or `org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker`.

So to figure out why this is happening, you should search in your classpath to find out how the `/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` resource is ending up in there.

Comment: And after I knew what to look for, it wasn't hard to find.  I was expecting to find it buried in a dependency, but apparently someone who worked on this service before had put the file in src/test/resources of the project itself, for what I"m sure was a good reason at the time. He's moved on, so I can't easily ask him, but I think I have enough to solve this.